# Firebase Notification Not Receive in onMessageReceived when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I an using `FCM` for sending a notification in my app and all work perfectly but when my app is in background then the notification is handle by android system notification tray

i want to handle my notification from myself i am sending this payload for send the notification

```
$fields = array(
        'notification' => $notification,
        'to'  => '/topics/updates'
        );
```

this will call my `onMessageReceived` when my app is in `forground` but when my app is in background this will not call my `onMessageReceived` the request is handled by system itself

i want to call my `onMessageReceived` when my app is in `background`

i am also try to remove `notification key` and only send `data key` like this

```
$fields = array(
        'data' => $notification,
        'to'  => '/topics/updates'
        );
```

but when i send the request from above field `onMessageReceived` is not called in both the condition in `forground and background`

i am try this in my `xiaomi redmi note 4 (oreo)` , `redmi 4x(android 10)` and `android emulator(marshmello)`

i am follow this ans for solve my problem but not work for me [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

my FCM version is `17.3.4`
and my android studio version is `3.5.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for post this stupid questions FCM work in background when we post only data key not notification key

my mistake is this i wrap my notification builder by this

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
 // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data message is not received then the payload might be wrong. Here is my payload example (.js, but the structure should be pretty much the same):

```
const  payload = {
            data: {
                title: finalTitle,
                body: message,
                icon: icon
            },
            topic: channel
        };

admin.messaging().send(payload)
        .then((response) => {
            return
        })
```

Comment: i tryed this payload not working in forground and background